# Using AJAX, JavaScript to call python flask function with return to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I know that you can have javascript to call a python flask function and be able to return data to a designated  id. Like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id = "update"> </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   var counter = 0;
   window.setInterval(function(){
      $("#update").load("/game?counter=" + counter);
      counter++;
   }, 5000)
```

**views.py**

```
from flask import request

@app.route("/game")
def live_game():
    textlist = ['a','b','c','d']
    counter = request.args.get('counter')
    return "<p> " + textlist[counter] + " </p>"
```

I found this in a previous post. What I would like to do is update utilize this method in updating some cool justgage that I found online to show the most up to date temperature and humidity readings from my database. Here is the script that I was wanting to use:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Historical Environmental Readings</h1>      
    <div class="container-fluid" id="dht-container">
      <div id="g1" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;"></div>
      <div id="g2" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

.....

```
<script>
        function ajaxd(NodeID) { 
        //reload result into element with id "dht-container"
        $(??????).load("/tempnodeDHT", function() {  alert( "Temp Load was performed." ); });

        
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
            var g1 = new JustGage({
                id: "g1",
                value: 50,
                min: -20,
                max: 150,
                title: "DHT Temp",
                label: "temperature",
                pointer: true,
                textRenderer: function (val) {
                    if (val < NODE_EnvCP.low_temp) {
                        return 'Cold';
                    } else if (val > NODE_EnvCP.hot) {
                        return 'Hot';
                    } else if (val === NODE_EnvCP.optimum_temp) {
                        return 'OK';
                    }
                },
            });
            var g2 = new JustGage({
                id: "g2",
                value: 50,
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
                title: "Target",
                label: "Humidity",
                pointer: true,
                textRenderer: function (val) {
                    if (val < NODE_EnvCP.low_hum) {
                        return 'LOW';
                    } else if (val > NODE_EnvCP.high_hum) {
                        return 'HIGH';
                    } else if (val === NODE_EnvCP.optimum_hum) {
                        return 'OK';
                    }
                },
            });

            setInterval(function () {
             (currentTemp, currentHumidity)=ajaxd();
            g1.refresh(currentTemp);
            g2.refresh(currentHumidity);
                return false;
            }, 2500);
        });
    </script>
```

This is my python flask function:
**run.py**

```
@app.route('/nodeDHT')
def getLatestDHT():
    NodeID = request.args.get('NodeID')
    df = DAO.Pull_CURRENT_DHT_Node_Data(self, NodeID)
    currentTemp = df.Temperature[0]
    currentHumidity = df.Humidity[0]
    return (currentTemp, currentHumidity)
```

I was hoping that I could change the ?????? inside

```
$(??????).load("/nodeDHT", function() {  alert( "Temp Load was performed." ); });
```

so that the two variables `(currentTemp, currentHumidity)` would end up back into the javascript portion so that the gages would update every 2.5 seconds. Also, am I passing the variable back to the python flask? there is a variable already pushed to the html when it was rendered.

EDIT:

could I do something like this:

```
@app.route('/nodeDHT')
def getLatestDHT():
    NodeID = request.args.get('NodeID')
    df = DAO.Pull_CURRENT_DHT_Node_Data(self, NodeID)
    currentTemp = df.Temperature[0]
    currentHumidity = df.Humidity[0]
    return json.dumps(currentTemp, currentHumidity)
```

and in the javascript side do something like this?

```
    function ajaxd(NodeID) { 
    //reload result into javascript
    $.get("/nodeDHT",function( currentTemp, currentHumidity ){ console.log($.parseJSON(currentTemp, currentHumidity)});
```

What I'm really asking is. How can I pass single/multiple variables to the python flask function from the javascript function and then get back a dataframe where I can use column values to update a chart or multiple variables back to the javascript function to be used in a setinterval to be used for multiple functions such as updating justgage

```
    setInterval(function () {
     (currentTemp, currentHumidity)=ajaxd();
    g1.refresh(currentTemp);
    g2.refresh(currentHumidity);
        return false;
    }, 2500);
```

---------------------DOUBLE EDIT -----------------------

COULD I DO SOMETHING LIKE THIS:

```
function UPDATEGAGES(NodeID) { 
$.get('/nodeDHT?NodeID='+NodeID+'&startdatetime='+startdatetime, 
    function(data){ const parsed = JSON.parse(data)};
        g1.refresh(currentTemp);
        g2.refresh(currentHumidity);
});

setInterval(function () {
        UPDATEGAGES(NodeID);
        return false;
    }, 2500);
```

Comment: So you want to use $.post() and not load HTML content

Comment: I don't know. would that bring the variables from 'getLatestDHT' back into the script area?

Comment: Wouldn't passing a JSON array/object be ideal here? jQuery even has a [$.getJSON](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) function to skip the JSON stringify/parse steps, although you still need to JSON (de)serialize server-side. In your example, you could probably just use a query parameter (e.g. `/nodeDHT?nodeId=123`), although you'd still have to serialize the response data.

Comment: I'm a noob to the javascript side of things...why would you not want to use ajax $.get  ? I thought that is the ideal method in returning dataframes from pandas to update charts and real time data

Comment: @Daniel Do you need to response with two variable in server side?

Comment: @Prana so, I need to be able to pass one to three variables back to the server (which is the python flask 'run.py' , I'm assuming is the server) and then I need to be able to pass one to three variables back as a response that I can use INSIDE the javascript for other functions (like the 'g1.refresh(currentTemp);' ). I also have an instance that I need to pass a pandas dataframe but I really don't know how to do those things fluidly. Please help.

Comment: @Daniel I've added an answer below. Check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send variables to server in get method, use variables in url

```
'/tempnodeDHT?NodeID='+your_nod_id+'&anotherVar='+value+'&anotherVar2='+value2
```

You can access them in your flask server as below

```
NodeID = request.args['NodeID']
anotherVar = request.args['anotherVar']
anotherVar2 = request.args['anotherVar2']
```

If you want to send multiple variables from flask server to your front end, send it as JSON

```
return jsonify({'currentTemp': currentTemp, 'currentHumidity': currentHumidity })
```

When you handle it the response from the server, again parses it to JSON.

```
$.get( '/nodeDHT/tempnodeDHT?NodeID='+your_nod_id+'&anotherVar='+value+'&anotherVar2='+value2, function( data ) {
  const parsed = JSON.parse(data)
  // here you can access your 'currentTemp' variable from parsed.currentTemp 
});
```

**EDIT**

For your final desired output

```
function UPDATEGAGES(NodeID, startdatetime) { 
    $.get('/nodeDHT?NodeID='+NodeID+'&startdatetime='+startdatetime, 
        function(data){
            const parsed = JSON.parse(data)
            g1.refresh(parsed.currentTemp);
            g2.refresh(parsed.currentHumidity);
        };
    )
};

setInterval(function () {
        UPDATEGAGES(NodeID, startdatetime);
        return false;
}, 2500);
```

Comment: ok...so I mistakenly put in tempnodeDHT instead of just /nodeDHT 

you are saying to use $.get('/nodeDHT?NodeID='+NodeID+'&startdatetime='+startdatetime, function(data){ const parsed = JSON.parse(data)...... so what I'm getting out of this is that the data returning will get parsed out to being currentTemp and currentHumidity ?

Comment: currentTemp and currentHumidity are the values returned from the server.

Comment: Good Sir, I will be testing this but I think you are the winner

Comment: and those values will be available within the <script> /....</script>  ?

Comment: No. there are available within that call back function only. (Because of closures). If you need to make it as global, assign them to window.currentTemp = parsed.currentTemp

Comment: so.. one more question...actually probably a lot more questions: could I do this:
function ajaxd(NodeID) { 
$.get('/nodeDHT?NodeID='+NodeID+'&startdatetime='+startdatetime, function(data){ const parsed = JSON.parse(data)};

            setInterval(function () {
            currentTemp,currentHumidity = ajaxd(NodeID);
            g1.refresh(currentTemp);
            g2.refresh(currentHumidity);
                return false;
            }, 2500);
        });

Comment: wait I'll add something at the bottom of my post

Comment: Added it. @Prana can you check this and see if I'm using this right?

Comment: ALSO, is there no way to pass a pandas dataframe over to the script from the python flask side?

Comment: @Daniel I've added answer to your previous question. For your second question, data should be in json format to be send as a response.

Comment: I thought I did. I'm sorry